# Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, jestjs, puppeteer

First time running jest, and I had some problems. Do you know what is missing?

Error:

```
> jest "fabre.spec.js"

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!

    at onClose (D:\TEMP\tests-e2e\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\BrowserRunner.js:193:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\TEMP\tests-e2e\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\BrowserRunner.js:184:79)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:333:22)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
```

### Set-up

Windows 7 / node v13.6.0 / npm  v6.14.8

Package.json

```
 {
....
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.5.3",
    "jest-image-snapshot": "^4.2.0",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^4.4.0",
    "puppeteer": "^5.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-puppeteer",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./setupJest.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: could you supply code for the file `fabre.spec.js` and also tell us what command you ran to get that error.

Comment: I solved it uninstalling and installing again chromium and pupetteer.